# What's the right approach when identical questions are getting opposite treatment?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, upvotes

I came across these two questions right next to each other in the New Questions list. The titles are nearly identical, the bodies discuss the same problem.

[image]

[iTunes Connect submit for review - Your app information could not be saved. Try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800116/itunes-connect-submit-for-review-your-app-information-could-not-be-saved-try)

[Your app information could not be saved. Try again - iTunesConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797041/your-app-information-could-not-be-saved-try-again-itunesconnect)

while the earlier question is a little more descriptive after edits, they basically look the same to me. Yet one is receiving up votes, the other down votes and is on hold. I can't see why the former question is better than the latter, nor why the latter would be off-topic instead of a dup.

So when I encounter this, is it more appropriate to just flag newer one as a dup? Or is it more appropriate to flag as "needs moderator attention?" Or is there some other course of action one should take?

Comment: A moderator could have merged them but that's too late now.  So vote to close as dup.  If you can't make up your mind which one is the canonical one and don't trust the downvoters to be right then just flip a coin.

Comment: I suspect the different treatment is due to one of the questions is not specific enough (not providing enough information)